# How should we welcome new users?

Tags: discussion

Once you get access to the review queues, one of the review types is "First Posts". Here experienced users are shown new users' first posts and asked to take an action.

What should we do at this point? I've just completed my first "first post" review, and the answer was good so I upvoted. I couldn't think of anything that needed saying, so I didn't comment.

Should we just take action that is needed, or should we have a standard wording to also comment and welcome to the site (for posts where no negative action is required)?

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion we should handle posts in the First Posts Queue and the Late Answers Queue the same way as posts we find when browsing questions usually. You don't post a comment when you find a "normal" post of a regular user, if you have nothing to say. Why do it for first posts?

Personally, I handle first posts *mostly* like other posts I see on sites where I have access to that queue. Except, if I have something to say, like suggestions for improvements, for first posts I usually start my comments with

> Welcome to Computer Graphics StackExchange.

(adapt to the respective site). But I only comment, if I have something to say beyond that.

I think that the purpose of the queue is more like to get some more attention to first posts than to greet new users.